# Spawning numerous AsyncTask instances - implications?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, bitmapfactory

I am designing an Android application targeting >= API 17.  I have created a class, DownloadImageTask which extends AsyncTask, and receives a string (URL) and an ImageView as arguments.  In it, I am opening an HTTP connection, downloading an image from a URL, and using BitmapFactory to create a Bitmap object from the data, then setting the bitmap to the ImageView.  The end result is a populated list of data which is available to the user to scroll through, with images populating as they can.

This appears to be a good design on the surface - but I am concerned that I am putting my app at risk for an OOM condition, or other violation of the user experience rules.  I'd like to know if the way I've designed this is correct, or if not, how I should approach this.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes.  This is very subject to problems and it's an issue that's been solved fairly well with image libraries like Picasso, Universal Image Loader, and these https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46.

Comment: You would need to be managing a good number of images, or not handling their scaling appropriately, to really run into issues, but yes you should look into one of the libraries that a large team spent long hours tuning for just this. Glide is also another good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two considerations to your own approach:

1. You shouldn't pass the ImageView to the async task because in that way you are coupling your view and your service layer. So send to the async task the URL, and onPostExecute method call to Activity which implement an updateView (or the like) method.
2. About your OOM, you are right. The problem might arise if you use the original bitmaps which could have larger resolution than required. Therefore you should scale down the images you keep in memory.

The last issue might not be difficult if you use a few images otherwise could be problematic. So if you will be working with a lot of images and you are not forced to implement your own version, you should have a look to the existing libraries. Some are already mentioned:

- [Glide](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/)
- [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: Based on the advice here, I've removed the AsyncTask from my project and replaced it with Glide.  Not only does this disconnect my UI from my service layer, but it provides a lot of other nice features.  Thank you all for your comments.